# Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Когда-то начинал учится на  android studio 3. Потом долго не было возможности и вот опять решил возобновить. Поставил 4.2.2 и при открытии любого проекта получаю ошибку:

```
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
> Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

```
Gradle sync failed: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (28 s 317 ms)
```

Гуглил, находил такие же проблемы, но тк английский у меня с гуглопереводчиком, то так и не понял что надо делать.

Помогите, пож, решить эту проблему.

Comment: Попробуй не открывать проект, а импортировать. И в gradle с тех пор поменялось `compile` на `implementation`

Comment: @DrMcSheen, спасибо, попробовал - та же история.

Comment: Ещё, в качестве танца с бубном, File-Invalidate Cash/Restart, Analise-InspectCode